# How to fix a bottom bar on soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to fix a bottom bar on soft keyboard. how could that be possible, I have done the following code but all my view goes up when the EditText is focused.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.Comment">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/textsend"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            >





            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/commenttext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textSendButton"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSend"
                android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" >
            </EditText>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/textSendButton"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#3D107B"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

and below here is how does it look like when trying to type something on the EditText

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the linear layout and keep everything in a relative layout instead. Do alignParentTop=true for the toolbar